# Swagger: How to handle a response containing a java 'object' class

Tags: java, swagger

I am trying to understand how to specify in "swagger" that the  response  is actually a object of class `"ViewObject.java"` which contains an object of class "Object" which in the example below contains an instance of `"App.java"`.
In the below code when I specify `@ApiOperation` as `"response = ViewObject.class"` it cannot figure out that in ViewObject the "result" field contains an instance of "App".

---

```
@GET
@Path("/app/{appCode}")
@Produces("application/json")
@ApiOperation(value = "Get App Configuration", response = ViewObject.class)
public @ResponseBody  ViewObject getApp(@PathParam("appCode") String appCode) throws FreemoException,Exception {
    App app = new App();
    app.setAppCode(appCode);
    ViewObject viewObject = new ViewObject();
    App appLoadedFromDB  = appService.getApp(app.getAppCode()); //Load App from DB

    viewObject.setStatus(FreemoStatus.SUCCESS);
    viewObject.setResult(appLoadedFromDB);
    return viewObject;
}
```

---

```
ViewObject.java:
    public class ViewObject  extends FreemoModel{
        private FreemoStatus status;
        private String message;
        private Object result;
    }
```

---

Comment: All the fields in `ViewObject` are private...

Comment: Thanks of the comments @Ron. I tried changing the fields to "public". No luck. Since "result" is of type "Object", it cannot detect the underlying class inside it. Is there a way to specify using Swagger API which class  it will contain?   This is what i see in swagger ui:  <pre> ------------------------------------------------
ViewObject {
message (string, optional),
status (FreemoStatus, optional) = ['EXCEPTION' or 'SUCCESS' or 'VALIDATION_ERROR'],
result (Object, optional)
} <pre> ------------------------------------------------

Comment: You can use `@ApiModelProperty#dataType()` to override the field's type.

Comment: @Ron: In that case, I will  have to add it in the ViewObject.java class for the "result" field right? .  The problem being that "ViewObject" is used by multiple rest calls and for each of these calls the "result" will be populated with different class instances. Like in this case "result" contains "App" class  instance but it could contain something else too.  Is there a way it can be specified  when making the "getApp()" method call instead ? maybe using some annotation?

Comment: I'm afraid that sounds like poor coding then. Why don't you use generics then? `ViewObject<T>`, and then `private T result;`?